# How to limit string length in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, substring

I have a 2-dimensional PHP array containing strings (`$fulltable`) which I'm trying to  fit into the datables grid (https://www.datatables.net/).

Sometimes some of the strings are really long. I'd like to truncate each string to lets say to 75 charachters, which will make the fields more manageable on display.

Is there an easy PHP function to do this or should I just create a double loop like this?

```
foreach ($fulltable as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $field) {
        // TRUNCATE FIELD HERE
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to do this and take the value by reference, e.g.

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function(&$v){
    $v = substr($v, 0, 75);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mb_substr`:

```
mb_substr($field, 0, 30);
```

Where 0 is the beginning and 30 is the end, 30 could be anything you want, the length of your output.

Answer (score 1):

[`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) or [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) will apply a function to the contents of an array (single dimension), and be probably faster that looping with `foreach`.

There is also [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) for multi dimensional arrays.